# IdentityServer3 does not redirect after login

Tags: c#, redirect, openid, identityserver3

I've implemented `IdentityServer3` and am using it for authenticating my users by using the following code:

```
if ( Request.IsAuthenticated == false )
{
      Request.GetOwinContext()
             .Authentication
             .Challenge( new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44300/About.aspx" },
                         OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType );
}
```

The above code redirect the user back to the About.aspx page (even though the current page is https://localhost:44300/Contact.aspx.

If I run my site in a application folder, in this example 'APPDIR' (not the root application) then the redirect back to the site does not work and I end up getting rerouted back to https://localhost:44300.

```
if ( Request.IsAuthenticated == false )
{
    Request.GetOwinContext()
           .Authentication
           .Challenge( new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44300/APPDIR/About.aspx" },
                                   OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType );
}
```

Any thoughts?

Kind regards,

Mark

Comment: RedirectUri should be relative.

Comment: When in Visual Studio I change my project URL to https://localhost:44300/FS/ 
and the code to 

<pre><code>

            if ( Request.IsAuthenticated == false )
            {
                Request.GetOwinContext()
                       .Authentication
                       .Challenge( new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "About.aspx" },
                                       OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType );
            }

</code></pre>

then I get redirected to https://localhost:44300 and not to https://localhost:44300/FS/About.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure what "in VS changing the URL to localhost:44300/FS" does. Does it create a proper application in IIS express? that affects the base path from Katana's perspective. Perhaps debug checking the OWIN request's BasePath.